# Stream Analytics not processing instantly, constant 5 second watermark

Tags: azure, watermark, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

We are trying to process event driven icons on a dashboard (on/off/active) with IoT hub, stream analytics, and table storage. I cannot get the actual process to work under 6 seconds. Watermark for stream analytics is a constant 5 seconds. The website claims instant processing. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/

I have setup stream analytics with a very simple query of storing the enqueued time into table storage. I made sure the event ordering times and out of order messages was all set to 0 seconds and drop. I did this with a new stream analytics deployment. Also used the max allowed SU of 6. I set the batch output to 1.

```
select IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId as PartitionKey, IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId as RowKey, IoTHub.EnqueuedTime As Value
into Output
from Input
```

I expect total processing to be under 1.5 seconds and the watermark to be under 100s of milliseconds.

Comment: I should add, this is with singular messages in development, so 1 every couple minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following alerts are recommended for monitoring the performance of your Stream Analytics job. These metrics should be evaluated every minute over the last 5-minute period.

[image]

Try increasing the number of SUs or parallelizing your query.

For more information on SUs, see [Understand and adjust Streaming Units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-streaming-unit-consumption#how-many-sus-are-required-for-a-job).

Hope this helps.

Comment: As my question stated, we have already tried the max allowed SU for the query given. We also set the late arrival tolerance to 0.

Even in the 1 minute granularity, the minimum watermark seen is 5 seconds.

Comment: I fail to see how parallelizing would help, we are sending very few messages right now, 1 every couple minutes from one device.

Comment: ParalleIizing was the answer. I didn't fully understand the exact details of why parallelizing would work, but it does when you do a partition by partitionId. This is due to the fact that Stream Analytics adds 5 seconds to account for clock skew between IoT Hub and Stream Analytics when one stream processes for multiple partitions. Making it 1:1 allows the stream to immediately process.